# Import Android-DirectoryChooser into Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I'm trying to include a directory-chooser feature in my Android app, but apparently I can't import the library I found. This is the library that I want to use: https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser.

I followed this steps:

- downloaded the zip file and imported it into Eclipse (Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace -> selected only library project). The tree now looks like this:

  [image]
- right-clicked on **main** project and checked **Is Library**
- right-clicked on **java** folder in the **main** project and selected **Use as Source folder**
- right-clicked on my project and added the **main** library in the Android tab; also added the library in the **Java Build Path** tab, that now looks like this:

  [image]

I don't know what I'm missing, but the line

`import net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity;`

gives me an error saying that **The import net cannot be resolved**. How can I correctly import this library?

Answer (score 0):

You have imported the library 'main' as a java library, instead import it as an Android Library. Follow steps mentioned in this link : 
[adding-android-library-project-to-eclipse-build-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968153/adding-android-library-project-to-eclipse-build-path)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that the [README](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser/blob/master/README.md) said:

> ... Import the project into your favorite IDE and add `android.library.reference.1=/path/to/Android-DirectoryChooser/library to your project.properties` ...

In fact [Android-DirectoryChooser](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser) support only gradle-based projects as result only Android Annotations

### How to fix it

To be able use it in you eclipse project you should:

1. Change library directory layout
2. Download third-party jar dependencies
3. Setup [Auto Parcel](https://github.com/frankiesardo/auto-parcel) annotation processing
4. Add library to your project

#### Change library directory layout

Directory layout should be plain, like below

```
directory-chooser
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── assets
├── libs
├── src
├── res
└── project.properties
```

#### Download third-party jar dependencies

After resloving all dependencies `libs` and `compile-libs` looks

```
...
├── compile-libs
│   ├── auto-parcel-processor-0.3.1.jar
│   └── guava-19.0-rc1.jar
├── libs
│   ├── auto-common-0.4.jar
│   ├── auto-parcel-0.3.1.jar
│   ├── auto-value-1.1.jar
│   └── option-1.3.jar
...
```

#### Setup annotation processing

For annotation processing you can just use approach from [androidannotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Configuration). Copy [custom_rules.xml](https://github.com/androidquickstart/androidannotations-example/blob/master/custom_rules.xml) for building with ant or fix `Factory Path` for building from eclipse

#### Add library to your project

Update your `project.properties` file, add `android.library.reference.1=/path/to/Android-DirectoryChooser/library`